# Change user password when user is login but I am getting error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my change password function. When this function is called using Postman it works but when I try to hit this from an app its giving an error.

```js
async function changePassword(req,res) {
    try {
      email = req.user.email;
      let user = await userModel.findOne({email: email});
      console.log(req.body.password+"dsddsd");
      console.log(req.body.oldPassword);
      if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.oldPassword, user.password)) {
        res.status(400).json({message : "Invalid Old Password"});
      } 
      else {
          req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
          try {
            await userModel.updateOne({email : email
            },{
                $set : {
                    password : req.body.password
                }
            });
            res.status(200).json({message : "Password Changed SuccessFully"});
          } catch (error) {
              res.status(500).json({message : "Something Went Wrong"});    
          }
      }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message : "Error"});

    }
};
```

I am getting the error:

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0

Comment: which line get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as follows:

```
async function changePassword(req,res) {
            try {
              email = req.user && req.user.email;
    //Added a extra check to make sure that payload is received as required.
          if(!email || !req.body.password || !req.body.oldPassword) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message : "Bad Request" });
          }
              let user = await userModel.findOne({email: email});
              console.log(req.body.password+"dsddsd");
              console.log(req.body.oldPassword);
              if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.oldPassword, user.password)) {
                res.status(400).json({message : "Invalid Old Password"});
              } 
              else {
                  req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
                  try {
                    await userModel.updateOne({email : email
                    },{
                        $set : {
                            password : req.body.password
                        }
                    });
                    res.status(200).json({message : "Password Changed SuccessFully"});
                  } catch (error) {
                      res.status(500).json({message : "Something Went Wrong"});    
                  }
              }
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json({message : "Error"});

            }
        };
```

As you said that the request works from postman then there are two possible causes:
 1. `Content-Type: application/json` is not set the in the request when being sent from app.
 2. The required payload is not getting passed in the request.

Please inspect the network tab in your chrome browser and check the request header and payload being passed to confirm.Also, you can copy the request as curl from browser network tab and compare the difference with your postman request